# Drop Database called "User" from Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

Ok this is what happend...

One of my colleges run a script that created some tables which included one table called "User" on an Oracle XE 10g. Now we are unable to drop that table, we get an [ORA-00903](http://ora-00903.ora-code.com/) every time we run a:

`DROP TABLE USER CASCADE CONSTRAINTS`

The same happens when ever we try to run any alter query on it (that means renaming doesn't work)

Do someone know how to deal with this?

Comment: How many colleges do you have? ;)

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: As many as mistakes that need a scapegoat. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried fully qualifying with quotes:

```
drop table "myschema"."user"
```

Comment: Should that be `"myschema"."user"`?

Comment: Yo'r the man! thanks a lot, my "college" will be very happy =)

Answer (score 2):

Randy is right suggesting quoted identifiers. Note however that [quoted identifiers are case-sensitive](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm).

First, query ALL_TABLES or USER_TABLES to find the case-sensitive name of that table, and use that name in a statement such as

```
DROP TABLE "User";
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE "User" RENAME TO TBL_USERS;
```